# Match overlay icons in spread/scale to icon theme [14.04]

Tags: unity, compiz, icons

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Compiz 0.9.11.3. Not all overlay icons in the spread mode match the icon theme.

For example: emacs24, gimp, libre office, Mathematica, Google-chrome, sublime.

---

[image]

[emacs had a hard coded path to the hicolor icon, but changing it didn't change the overlay icon (even after restarting unity/compiz).]

Comment: could you please add a screenshot?